# Difference between two 2D histograms

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot the difference between two 2D histograms. For example, consider the following code:

```
from numpy import c_
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors


n = 100000

x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 3.0 * x + 2.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)

x1 = np.random.normal(loc=-2, scale=5, size=n)
y1 = (x1)**2 + np.random.standard_normal(n)

plt.figure(1)
h, xedges, yedges, image = plt.hist2d(x,y, bins=50, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap = plt.cm.rainbow)

plt.figure(2)
h1, xedges1, yedges1, image1 = plt.hist2d(x1,y1, bins=50, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap = plt.cm.rainbow)
```

Is it possible to plot the difference between them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in bin-to-bin or cross-bin comparison?

Comment: Make the `bins=(xedges, yedges)` and make those the same between each call to `plt.hist2d` (or use the edges from the first call in the second), and then you can just do `imshow(h-h1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors


n = 100000

x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 3.0 * x + 2.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)

x1 = np.random.normal(loc=-2, scale=5, size=n)
y1 = (x1)**2 + np.random.standard_normal(n)

plt.figure(1)
h, xedges, yedges, image = plt.hist2d(x,y, bins=(50, 60), norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap = plt.cm.rainbow)

plt.figure(2)
h1, xedges1, yedges1, image1 = plt.hist2d(x1,y1, bins=(xedges, yedges), norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap = plt.cm.rainbow)

plt.figure(3)
plt.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, (h-h1).T)

plt.show()
```

For some reason every statistics function in matplotlib returns things transposed, but you get the idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As from my side, you can do manipulation with arrays, to find **.._diff** values and then plot.
Example:

```
x_diff = x - x1
y_diff = y - y1 
h_diff, xedges_diff, yedges_diff, image_diff = plt.hist2d(x_diff, y_diff, bins=50, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap = plt.cm.rainbow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two big classes of comparison functions : bin-to-bin comparison and cross-bin comparison.

- Bin-to-bin comparison : Standard sum of differences is quite bad.
  There's an improvement, the Chi-squared distance.
- Cross-bin comparison : A standard example called the bin-similarity matrix requires some similarity matrix M where in M(i,j) is the similarity between the bins i and j. The distance between histograms H1 and H2 would be sqrt((H1-H2)*M*(H1-H2)). Earth Moving Distance (EMD) is another kind of cross-bin distance.

[This paper](https://www.cse.huji.ac.il/%7Ewerman/Papers/ECCV2010.pdf) introduces you to histogram distances in a nice way.

To sum up, you need to better define what the difference means in your case.

Edit: I think that the easiest thing to do and at the same time to be scientifically correct is using [opencv's implementation of the histogram comparison](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dc8/tutorial_histogram_comparison.html) which includes metrics such as intersection of histograms, Bhattacharyya distance, chi-square etc.

```
cv.compareHist(hist_1, hist_2, compare_method)
```

Comment: Thank you, azal. That's a good point. I think my question is incomplete. Considering the provided example, we see that h1 values extend further xedges1 < -5 and yedges1 > 15, which are in turn the limits of h. In the 'difference map', such values must be present in the correct positions. Thinking better now, instead of bin-to-bin or cross-bin comparison, maybe should I create a common grid and make the 'difference' between distributions in such a grid?

Comment: What is the question you want to answer? Do you want to see "how" similar the 2 histograms are? Or do you want to just plot their "difference" which practically does not mean much?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: Dear azal, sorry for the delay. I was testing the different approaches. The answer that suited me the most was the one proposed by @Jody Klymak. I created a common grid to be used with the datasets and then I subtracted 'h' from 'h1'. I will update my answer with the solution. Cheers and thank you for the help.